# Javascript first complete unicode character from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

Getting the first character in a string is fairly straightforward.

```js
const str = 'abc'
str[0] // 'a'
```

However, when javascript sees a unicode string, it will return the first byte of a multi-byte unicode character.

```js
const strUnicode = 'hi'
strUnicode[0] // '�'
```

Is it possible to return the first complete unicode character?

```js
const strUnicode = 'hi'
f(strUnicode) // ''
```

Comment: `String.fromCodePoint('hi'.codePointAt(0));` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that symbols are 16-bit characters. So it takes 2 positions in a character array.

#### Idea:

- Loop over string and validate if current character is a symbol or not.
- If symbol, take character at `i` and `i+1`. Increment `i` to skip the processed character
- If not, just pick one character

```js
function getCharacters(str) {
  const parts = []
  for(let i = 0; i< str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt( i ) > 255) {
      parts.push(str.substr(i, 2))
      i++
    } else {
      parts.push(str[i])
    }
  }
  return parts
}

const strUnicode = 'hi'
console.log( getCharacters(strUnicode) )
```

Comment: Not deleting the answer as this approach is not there in linked post. Also yes, mentioned method is better to use but I'll keep it as an alternative

Comment: `"‍‍".length === 8` - there are characters with greater than 2 positions